# Get all properties which implements a specific generic base type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have an object which has generic collection properties of different types like this:

```
ObservableCollection<T>, BindingList<T>
```

I want to return all properties which implement `ICollection<>`. I tried this with no success. It seems this query using reflection doesn't check the implemented interfaces:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> childCollections =
    typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
               && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        .Select(g => g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly querying the property's type, meaning it must itself be of the specific type `ICollection<>`. To check whether it *implements* the interface, you need `.GetInterfaces()`:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> childCollections =
  from p in typeof(T).GetProperties()
  where p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
    i.IsGenericType && 
    i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
  )
  select p
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following code and it is working quite well.

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(m =>
                    m.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                    m.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));
```

I have a class collections defined as :

```
public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Comment: This works only if you declare your collection properties of type ICollection<>. My Collection propertys are of type  ObservableCollection<T>, BindingList<T> and i cant change this.